# Replacing attribute value based on multiple conditions

Tags: java, xml, xslt

xml file-

```
<mydocument>
    <ol outputclass="abc">
        <li>
            <p>
                This is a regular ol,
                and outputclass= abc without linum.
            </p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>This is a regular ol,
                and outputclass= abc without linum.</p>
        </li>
    </ol>
    <ol outputclass="static">
        <li>
            <linum>3.</linum>
            <p>
                Here we use linum with an ol and outputclass=”static”.              
            </p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <linum>4.</linum>
            <p>Here we use linum with an ol and outputclass=”static”.
            </p>
        </li>
        
    </ol>
    <ol outputclass="static">
        <li>
            <p>This is ol with outputclass as static without linum element
            </p>
        </li>
    </ol>
</mydocument>
```

Xsl file-

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" version="2.0">

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@outputclass">
        <xsl:attribute name="outputclass">
            <xsl:choose>
                 <xsl:when test=". ='static'">              
                    <xsl:text>continue()</xsl:text>                 
                </xsl:when>
                
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:value-of select="." />
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
            
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>
    <!-- drop linum elements and its value -->
    <xsl:template match="ol/li/linum">
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I am trying to replace outputclass value from static to continue() if there is linum element found inside ol/li tag and also want to remove linum tag completely. I am able to achieve this for my second ol but it is also replacing the third ol outputclass value which ideally should not because it has not linum element inside.

Output I am getting-

```
<mydocument>
    <ol outputclass="abc">
        <li>
            <p>
                This is a regular ol,
                and outputclass= abc without linum.
            </p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>This is a regular ol,
                and outputclass= abc without linum.
            </p>
        </li>
    </ol>
    <ol outputclass="continue()">
        <li>

            <p>Here we use linum with an ol and outputclass=”static”.
            </p>
        </li>

        <li>
            <p>Here we use linum with an ol and outputclass=”static”.
            </p>
        </li>
    </ol>
    <ol outputclass="continue()">
        <li>
            <p>This is ol with outputclass as static without linum element
            </p>
        </li>
    </ol>
</mydocument>
```

Desired output-

```
<mydocument>
    <ol outputclass="abc">
        <li>
            <p>
                This is a regular ol,
                and outputclass= abc without linum.
            </p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>This is a regular ol,
                and outputclass= abc without linum.
            </p>
        </li>
    </ol>
    <ol outputclass="continue()">
        <li>

            <p>Here we use linum with an ol and outputclass=”static”.
            </p>
        </li>

        <li>

            <p>Here we use linum with an ol and outputclass=”static”.
            </p>
        </li>
    </ol>
    <ol outputclass="static">
        <li>
            <p>This is ol with outputclass as static without linum element
            </p>
        </li>
    </ol>
</mydocument>
```

Comment: Hello and welcome. Why the [java] tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the attribute use the template

```
<xsl:template match="ol[.//linum]/@outputclass[. = 'static']">
    <xsl:attribute name="outputclass">continue()</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

together with the other two templates you have.